# An error occurs when scrolling the list in ios16. What should I do?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, scroll, ios16

**An error occurs when the Add button is pressed. On ios15 it worked fine.**

On ios 15 it worked fine. but on ios16
An error occurs when the Add button is touched. I don't know why. Help.

Error: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1068e25ec)

```
public struct ListTest2: View
{
    @State var data: [Int] = []
    
    public var body: some View
    {
        ScrollViewReader
        { proxy in
            VStack
            {
                Button {
                    proxy.scrollTo(data.count - 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("goto end")
                }
                
                Button {
                    proxy.scrollTo(1)
                } label: {
                    Text("goto start")
                }
                
                
                Button {
                    data.append(data.count + 1)
                    proxy.scrollTo(data.count - 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Add")
                }
                                
                List {
                    
                    ForEach(data, id:\.self)
                    { index in
                        Text("\(index )")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear()
            {
                for index in 1...30 {
                    data.append(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug with List and ScrollviewReader. You could use a ScrollView instead of List as workaround.

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to be a bug in iOS 16.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed in ios16.4 version.